# Stand-alone portable snprintf(), independent of the standard library?

Tags: c, embedded, cross-platform, portability, printf

I am writing code for a target platform with `NO C-runtime`. `No stdlib`, `no stdio`. I need a string formatting function like `snprintf` but that should be `able to run without any dependencies`, not even the C library.

At most it can depend on `memory alloc functions` provided by me.

I checked out `Trio` but it needs `stdio.h header`.  I can't use this.

**Edit**

Target platform : `PowerPC64 home made OS`(not by me). However the library shouldn't rely on OS specific stuff.

**Edit2**

I have tried out some 3rd-party open source libs, such as Trio(http://daniel.haxx.se/projects/trio/), snprintf and miniformat(https://bitbucket.org/jj1/miniformat/src) but all of them rely on headers like string.h, stdio.h, or(even worse) stdlib.h. I don't want to write my own implementation if one already exists, as that would be time-wasting and bug-prone.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: How are you planning to support the I18N requirements?  There's a lot of work ahead of you.  If you can't use `<stdarg.h>`, you've got major problems (or you've got to simulate that, too, which is not trivial, in general).  How portable does your code need to be?  What are the names and the interfaces of the memory allocation functions?  Etc.

Comment: Obviously you need `<stdarg.h>`, for the rest you could modify any free implementation of snprintf. You only need to map the library calls to your own platform dependent functions

Comment: With respect to Trio (or any other implementation), remove the stdio.h inclusion and fix what breaks, I cannot imagine the dependency is that strong - it may even be only for the standard prototype declaration.

Comment: The portable implementation of `snprintf()` is actually trivial: `int snprintf(char *buffer, size_t buflen, char const *fmt, ...) { va_list args; va_start(args, fmt); int rv = vsnprintf(buffer, buflen, fmt, args); va_end(args); return rv; }` but that merely defers the pain to writing `vsnprintf()` (which is why this is a comment, not an answer).  It is, however, solid advice; write the varargs function (like `snprintf()`) in terms of a function that takes a `va_list` (like `vsnprintf()`).  Expose both interfaces.

Answer (score 7):

Try using the snprintf implementation from uclibc.  This is likely to have the fewest dependencies.  A bit of digging shows that snprintf is implemented in terms of vsnprintf which is implemented in terms of vfprintf (oddly enough), it uses a fake "stream" to write to string.

This is a pointer to the code: http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdio/_vfprintf.c

Also, a quick google search also turned up this:

- http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/
- http://yallara.cs.rmit.edu.au/~aholkner/psnprintf/psnprintf.html
- http://www.jhweiss.de/software/snprintf.html

Hopefully one is suitable for your purposes.  This is likely to not be a complete list.

There is a different list here:
http://trac.eggheads.org/browser/trunk/src/compat/README.snprintf?rev=197

Comment: [This implementation](ftp://ftp.jhweiss.de/pub/users/weiss/snprintf/snprintf.c) is free of a license and has pretty clear usage instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably at least need `stdarg.h` or low level knowledge of the specific compiler/architecture calling convention in order to be able to process the variadic arguments.

I have been using code based on [Kustaa Nyholm's implementation](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/tinyprintf.php)  It provides `printf()` (with user supplied character output stub) and `sprintf()`, but adding `snprintf()` would be simple enough.  I added `vprintf()` and `vsprintf()` for example in my implementation.

No dynamic memory application is required, but it does have a dependency on stdarg.h, but as I said, you are unlikely to be able to get away without that for any variadic function - though you could potentially implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are in a norming enivronment where you need to explicitly document and verify COTS code.

However, I think in the case of stdarg.h this is worthwhile. You could pull in the source for just this and treat it like handwritten code (review, lint, unit-test, etc.). Any self-written replacement will be a lot of work, probably less stable and absolutely not portable.

That said, the actual snprintf implementation should not be too hard, and you could do this yourself, probably. Especially if you might be able to strip a few features away.

Keep in mind that vararg code has no typechecking and is prone to errors. For library snprintf you may find gcc's warnings helpful.